# Strange error while expanding parameter pack containing lambda types

Tags: c++, lambda, type-traits, parameter-pack

I have a function which looks like `foo` in the following example:

```cpp
template <typename... Parameters>
void foo(std::function<void (Parameters &)>... functions) {
    // does interesting things with these functions
}
```

Now I want to call this function with some lambdas, e.g. like this:

```cpp
foo([](const std::string & string) {});
```

Unfortunately that doesn't work, because I get the following error:

```
error: no matching function for call to 'foo'
note: candidate template ignored: could not match 'function<void (type-parameter-0-0 &)>' against '(lambda at file.cpp:50:23)'
```

AFAIK, that is, because lambdas cannot be implicitly converted to `std::functions` like that.

One way to solve this problem is to manually wrap the lambdas in `std::function` like so:

```cpp
foo(std::function<void (const std::string &)>([](const auto & string) {}));
```

But for multiple lambdas this would get very tedious.

To get around this problem, I tried to create a wrapper function which detects the parameter type of the lambdas it gets passed using a helper type, and then wraps the lambda in the correct `std::function` type. Here is this wrapper function for only a single parameter (i.e. not variadic):

```cpp
template <typename Function>
void fooWrapped(Function && function) {
    foo(std::function<void (typename FunctionTypeTraits<Function>::ParameterType &)>(function));
}
```

The helper type `FunctionTypeTraits` is implemented like this:

```cpp
template <typename Function>
class FunctionTypeTraits:
    public FunctionTypeTraits<decltype(&std::remove_reference<Function>::type::operator())> {};

template <typename Param>
class FunctionTypeTraits<void (&)(Param &)> {
    typedef Param ParameterType;
};
```

Now I can call the wrapper function with my lambda and the compiler is perfectly happy:

```cpp
fooWrapped([](const std::string & string) {});
```

In principle, I should now be able to make `fooWrapper` variadic like so:

```cpp
template <typename... Functions>
void fooWrapped(Functions &&... functions) {
    foo((std::function<void (typename FunctionTypeTraits<Functions>::ParameterType &)>(functions))...);
}
```

That doesn't work however. If I call this new function with the exact same code, I get the following error:

```
error: 'std::remove_reference<void ((lambda at file.cpp:50:23)::*)(const std::string &) const>::type' (aka 'void ((lambda at file.cpp:50:23)::*)(const std::string &) const') is not a class, namespace, or enumeration
```

I don't quite understand this error. Why does the same approach work for a single template type, but not for an expanded parameter pack? Is this maybe just a compiler bug?
Is there another way, I could achieve my goal of calling `foo` using lambdas, without manually wrapping each of them in a `std::function`?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The type of address of lambda's `operator()` is `void (Lambda::*)(Param&) const` not `void (&)(Param &)`, you need to define the base case of your `FunctionTypeTraits` as:

```
template <typename Function>
struct FunctionTypeTraits:
  public FunctionTypeTraits<decltype(&std::remove_reference<Function>::type::operator())> {};

template <typename Lambda, typename Param>
struct FunctionTypeTraits<void (Lambda::*)(Param) const> {
  typedef Param ParameterType;
};
```

Another point is that in your `fooWrapped`, the type of specify for `std::function` should be `void (typename FunctionTypeTraits<Function>::ParameterType)` instead of just `ParameterType` since the latter is not a function type:

```
template <typename... Function>
void fooWrapped(Function&&... function) {
  foo(std::function<void (typename FunctionTypeTraits<Function>::ParameterType)>(function)...);
}
```

[Demo.](https://godbolt.org/z/Gc9a7T476)

Comment: Oh ok. Your second point was actually just a mistake on Stackoverflow and not actually how I tried it. I will edit my question to correct this. But with the first it seems to work now. I'm curious as to why it worked with the non-variadic function but not with parameter packs...

Comment: I haven't seen it [work](https://godbolt.org/z/jrG3szxnd), can you provide a reproduced example?

Comment: Apparently my IDE shows the errors with the variadic example but not with the non-variadic one...I could only see them once I built the code. I should really test things before I claim them to be true...sorry about that. And thanks for your help!